# Emacs org-mode timer - can it be shown in the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, taskbar, org-mode

I use Emacs org-mode for organizing my tasks and projects and also for time tracking.
However, I'm working a lot in other applications (mostly Microsoft Office 2007 or Firefox), so the Emacs Window is often in the background and not visible.

For time tracking it would be useful to **have the running clock visible all the time** to see how time is passing (similar to a pomodoro timer).

Is there a way to synchronize the display of this Emacs status bar (or an element of it) with the Windows 7 Taskbar?

Comment: Ask the orgmode list if you don't get an answer here: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode